# JQuery .width() doesn't change the width

Tags: javascript, html

I have got two divs, one img and one video, which adjusts to the size of the screen automatically. I want my image to be the same width with the video and found this code on the web (`.you` is the video and `.santa` is the image):

```
<script> 
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        $(".santa").width($(".you").width());
    });            
</script>
```

It does not change the width though.

Comment: You're adding an event to the "window.resize" handler. Have you tried resizing your window and seeing if your image gets the width?

Comment: Sure, that's what I was doing

Comment: when you can't adjust an element's width it usually means the display property is something line `display: inline;` which can't have widths. Have you tried setting the css property of the image to `display: block` so that it can have it's widths set? alternatively, have you logged the value of `$(".you").width()` so ensure you actually have a value there as well?

Answer (score 0):

It changes the width I wrote an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m9vo40we/) for you, to check it just resize the page splitter

```html
<div class="santa" style="width:100px;background-color:red">
santa
  <div class="you" style="width:200px;background-color:green">
    you
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $(".santa").width($(".you").width());
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work for me. Can it be the matter with my browser? I'm using Safari

Comment: Yes sometimes browsers don't support some features but I've tried it in Chrome 95 and Firefox 80 and it's worked  properly

Comment: Ok then, will try to do that in Chrome. Thank you :)

Comment: But no, it doesn't work... Something I've noticed right now is that you have div YOU embedded in div SANTA. But in my code they are parallel all embedded in another div. Not sure if it matters...